# Rolling joins: roll forwards and backwards

Tags: r, data.table

`data.table` is awesome, because I can do rolling joins, and even do rolling joins *within groups*!

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(42)
metrics <- data.frame(
  ID=c(rep(1, 10), rep(2,5), rep(3,5)),
  Time=c(1:10, 4:8, 8:12),
  val1=runif(20),
  val2=runif(20),
  val3=runif(20),
  val4=runif(20)
  )
metrics <- data.table(metrics[sample(1:nrow(metrics), 15),], key=c('ID', 'Time'))
calendar <- data.table(expand.grid(ID=1:3, Time=1:12), key=c('ID', 'Time'))

metrics[calendar,roll=TRUE]
```

However, this isn't awesome enough for me.  This `data.table` still has NAs:

```
> metrics[calendar,roll=TRUE]
    ID Time      val1      val2      val3        val4
 1:  1    1 0.9148060 0.9040314 0.3795592 0.675607275
 2:  1    2 0.9370754 0.1387102 0.4357716 0.982817198
 3:  1    3 0.9370754 0.1387102 0.4357716 0.982817198
 4:  1    4 0.8304476 0.9466682 0.9735399 0.566488424
 5:  1    5 0.8304476 0.9466682 0.9735399 0.566488424
 6:  1    6 0.5190959 0.5142118 0.9575766 0.189473935
 7:  1    7 0.7365883 0.3902035 0.8877549 0.271286615
 8:  1    8 0.7365883 0.3902035 0.8877549 0.271286615
 9:  1    9 0.6569923 0.4469696 0.9709666 0.693204820
10:  1   10 0.7050648 0.8360043 0.6188382 0.240544740
11:  1   11 0.7050648 0.8360043 0.6188382 0.240544740
12:  1   12 0.7050648 0.8360043 0.6188382 0.240544740
13:  2    1        NA        NA        NA          NA
14:  2    2        NA        NA        NA          NA
15:  2    3        NA        NA        NA          NA
16:  2    4 0.4577418 0.7375956 0.3334272 0.042988796
17:  2    5 0.7191123 0.8110551 0.3467482 0.140479094
18:  2    6 0.9346722 0.3881083 0.3984854 0.216385415
19:  2    7 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
20:  2    8 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
21:  2    9 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
22:  2   10 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
23:  2   11 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
24:  2   12 0.2554288 0.6851697 0.7846928 0.479398564
25:  3    1        NA        NA        NA          NA
26:  3    2        NA        NA        NA          NA
27:  3    3        NA        NA        NA          NA
28:  3    4        NA        NA        NA          NA
29:  3    5        NA        NA        NA          NA
30:  3    6        NA        NA        NA          NA
31:  3    7        NA        NA        NA          NA
32:  3    8 0.9400145 0.8329161 0.7487954 0.719355838
33:  3    9 0.9400145 0.8329161 0.7487954 0.719355838
34:  3   10 0.1174874 0.2076590 0.1712643 0.375489965
35:  3   11 0.4749971 0.9066014 0.2610880 0.514407708
36:  3   12 0.5603327 0.6117786 0.5144129 0.001570554
    ID Time      val1      val2      val3        val4
```

I could fill these NA's using `zoo:::na.locf`, `fromLast=TRUE`, but that's not very fun.  Can anyone think of an elegant way I can roll NA's *backward*, (after rolling them forward), during the `data.table` join?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is possible in **data.table** version 1.8.8 released March 2013:

```
metrics[calendar, roll=TRUE, rollends=c(TRUE, TRUE)]
```

From the [**data.table** NEWS file](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/NEWS):

> In addition to TRUE/FALSE, 'roll' may now be a positive number (roll forwards/LOCF) or
>           negative number (roll backwards/NOCB). A finite number limits the distance a value is
>           rolled (limited staleness). roll=TRUE and roll=+Inf are equivalent.
>           'rollends' is a new parameter holding two logicals. The first observation is rolled
>           backwards if the first value of rollends is TRUE. The last observation is rolled forwards if the second value of rollends
>           is TRUE. If roll is a finite number, the same limit applies to the ends.
>           New value roll='nearest' joins to the nearest value (either backwards or forwards) when
>           the value falls in a gap, and to the end value according to 'rollends'.
>           'rolltolast' has been deprecated. For backwards compatibility it is converted to
>           {roll=TRUE;rollends=c(FALSE,FALSE)}.

As always, to download the most up-to-date version of **data.table**, see [Installation](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: I cannot understand this " The first observation is rolled backwards if rollends1 is TRUE". Does that mean it will join on values LESS THAN if roll=+Inf

Answer (score 8):

`metrics[calendar, roll = TRUE, rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)]`