# calculating distance between two row in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

**Summary of problem:** I am cleaning up a fish telemetry dataset (i.e., spatial coordinates through time) using the `data.table` package (version 1.9.5) in `R` (version) on a Windows 7 PC. Some of data points are wrong (e.g., the telemetry equipment picked up echos). We can tell these points are wrong because the fish moved a farther distance than is biologically possible and stand out as outliers. The actual dataset contains over 2,000,000 rows of data from 30 individual fish, hence the use of the `data.table` package.

I am removing points that are too far apart (i.e., distance traveled is greater than a maximum distance). However, I need to recalculate distance traveled between points after removing a point because 2-3 data points were sometimes misrecorded in clusters. Currently, I have a `for` loop that gets the job done, but is likely far from optimal and I know that I am likely missing some of the powerful tools in the `data.table` package.

As technical notes, my spatial scale is small enough that a Euclidean distance works and my maximum distance criteria is biology reasonable.

**Where I have looked for help:** I have looked through SO and found several helpful answers, but none exactly match my problem. Specifically, all of the other answers only compare one column of data to among rows.

1. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25718669/4205652) compares two rows using `data.table`, but only looks at one variable.
2. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30605112/4205652) looks promising and uses `Reduce`, but I could not figure out how to use `Reduce` with two columns.
3. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17533201/4205652) uses an indexing feature from `data.table`, but I could not figure out how to use it with a distance function.
4. Last, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890004/rolling-joins-roll-forwards-and-backwards/15890096#15890096) demonstrates the `roll` function of `data.table`. However, I could not figure out how to use two variables with this function either.

**Here is my MVCE:**

```
library(data.table)
## Create dummy data.table
dt <- data.table(fish = 1,
                 time = 1:6,
                 easting = c(1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4),
                 northing = c(1, 2, 10, 11, 3, 4))
dt[ , dist := 0]

maxDist = 5

## First pass of calculating distances 
for(index in 2:dim(dt)[1]){
    dt[ index,
       dist := as.numeric(dist(dt[c(index -1, index),
                list(easting, northing)]))]
}

## Loop through and remove points until all of the outliers have been
## removed for the data.table. 
while(all(dt[ , dist < maxDist]) == FALSE){
    dt <- copy(dt[ - dt[ , min(which(dist > maxDist))], ])
    ## Loops through and recalculates distance after removing outlier  
    for(index in 2:dim(dt)[1]){
        dt[ index,
           dist := as.numeric(dist(dt[c(index -1, index),
                    list(easting, northing)]))]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a little confused why you keep recomputing the distance (and needlessly copying data) instead of just doing a single pass:

```
last = 1
idx = rep(0, nrow(dt))
for (curr in 1:nrow(dt)) {
  if (dist(dt[c(curr, last), .(easting, northing)]) <= maxDist) {
    idx[curr] = curr
    last = curr
  }
}

dt[idx]
#   fish time easting northing
#1:    1    1       1        1
#2:    1    2       2        2
#3:    1    5       3        3
#4:    1    6       4        4
```

Comment: I was passing though the data twice and copying because I could not figure out a single pass solution :). Thank you for your answer!